# Only top half area with polar.plot?

Tags: r, plotrix

I wonder whether there is any possibility to limit the the area of the polar chart to the top half area using polar.plot from package plotrix, i.e. plot only area between 0° and 180°?

I want this graph

[image]

look like this graph

[image]

**EDIT**

Sorry, here is a small reproducible data set:

```
structure(list(length = c(2, 2.5, 5.75, 5.25, 0, 0.75), axis = c(170, 12.9999990463257, 165, 21, 0, 74)), .Names = c("length", "axis"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

The plot generating function is:

```
library(plotrix)

polar.plot(ex.data$length,ex.data$axis,radial.lim=seq(0,8,1),
       labels=seq(0,350,10),label.pos =seq(0,350,10),  rp.type="s", point.col="black", line.col="black")
```

Comment: It is often useful to include code and data that make the plot reproducible. A small set of data that makes it reproducible can be created by using `dput(data)` (assuming `data` is the variable that contains your data).

Comment: When you edit your post, please put the images in the post and not just a link to them.

Comment: An apology isn't necessary, the comments are just to help improve things :-)